# Trying to build a simple Observer-Observable

Tags: java, observable, observer-pattern

I'm trying to build a simple Observer-Observable and when I call the `notifyObservers();`, it doesn't work and keeps on.  Someone knows what to do?

Class P:

```
import java.util.Observable;

public class P extends Observable{
   public void func(){
       notifyObservers();       
   }

}
```

Class Ob:

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class Ob implements Observer{

    P p;
    public Ob(P p) {
        this.p=p;
    }

    public void run(){

        p.func();

    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("SUceesssed");
    }

}
```

Run:

```
public class run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    P p=new P();

        Ob o=new Ob(p);
        p.addObserver(o);
        o.run();
    }

}
```

Comment: `notifyObservers()` will do anything only when the Observable has changed, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers()

Comment: how can i do it without changing just to jump the update method?

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `hasChanged()` before notifying the observers

```
  public class P extends Observable{
   public void func(){
     hasChanged();
     notifyObservers();
   }

 }
```

Comment: how can i do it without changing just to jump the update method?